# How many different subsets of a $2$-element set are there where the subsets have less than $1$ element?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> How many different subsets of a  $2$-element set are there where the subsets have less than $1$ element?

Let $A =  {2,0}

Then $\mathcal P(A) = \big\{\{2,0\},\{2\},\{0\},\{∅\}\big\}$

None of the subsets have element less than $1$. So the answer is $0$. Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit wrong to say $P(A)$ = {{$2$,$0$},{$2$},{$0$},{$∅$}} as in OP; instead, it should be
$$P(A)=\{\{0,2\},\{0\},\{2\},\emptyset\}$$

Notice that $\{\emptyset\}$ meaning a non-empty set, which has one element as $\emptyset$ - thus, it is not a subset of $A$. Instead $\emptyset $ is a subset of $A$.

**EDIT**
I think you might get a bit confused about empty set. One thing you should be clear about is that 
$$\emptyset \ne \{\emptyset\}$$

Once you are clear about that, you'll be clear about the answer.

Comment: so the answer is 0?

Comment: @socrates No, the answer is 1, because the $\emptyset$ is the ONE subset of $A$ that has element less than $1$. The point is that you need to realize that $\emptyset \ne \{\emptyset\}$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $1$, as $∅$ is a set of $0$ items, which is definitely less than $1$.

Comment: If the empty set is a set of zero items, wouldn't the answer be $1$ ?

Comment: Typo Crud I typed wrong (I'm kind of brain dead right now :D)

Comment: Your answer is not quite right.. $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set with one element.

Comment: Is it good now?